# How do I pass a string with escape character in a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts-1

Problem:

```
<a href="javascript:callNullify('<nested:write name="leaveApplicationElement"  property="leaveDetail"/>')"return false; >Select</a>
```

This 'leaveDetail' Field is Escape character and String. This is not pass to JavaScript function.

```
function callNullify(leaveDetail){
}
```

It is Input of LeaveDetail.
Ex: 
It's a 'Problem'.

Comment: well the `return false` is not inside the quotes. Problem 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="javascript:callNullify('<nested:write name='leaveApplicationElement' property='leaveDetail'>')"return false; >Select</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping the data first using this:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="javascript:callNullify('<nested:write name=&#8220;leaveApplicationElement&#8221;  property=&#8220;leaveDetail&#8221;/>'); return false;">Select</a>
```

Some thing like this : http://jsfiddle.net/ZeJuu/1/

Comment: Not Work Properly Friends

Comment: Can you tell me, how do you use that passed xml data?

Comment: The data is: i'm fever. So, I can't come to office.

Comment: You can escape single quote with: \\'

Comment: Friend, This value is dynamically got from jsp form. So, I can't any changes in the value.

Comment: That's fine. But while creating html with those details you will need to escape the special characters there. And you can do it with a replace function for single quotes and may be for double quote too.

Comment: Friend, I got solution for that Problem. Thanks For Your Co-operation.